# Rhino3D: how to use the object created later after closing grasshopper

Tags: grasshopper, rhino3d

I am new to Grasshopper. I did a very simple thing today and made a nice mesh. How can I use the mesh created?

While Grasshopper is open I can make no changes to the created mesh in Rhino3D. However, closing Grasshopper will make the object (mesh) disappear.

Am I missing a step? I need to continue manipulating the object created by Grasshopper.

Thank you.

Comment: I think bake should be the way to go: just see a tutorial, where they actualy used the things they created: https://youtu.be/XYvPQ9mx_cI?t=313

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "use the mesh".

As suggested in a comment, you can right-click the component that produces the final mesh, then click Bake.

You may find that you get faster and more informed answers about Grasshopper at https://discourse.mcneel.com/c/grasshopper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are working on reference lines and areas. Try to create original surfaces and close